# Visual Studio Team Services - Migrate Work Items/Sprints/Checkin Associations from TFVC to Git

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, azure-devops, git-tfs

I recently have been going through the steps to move our Visual Studio Team Services projects from using TFS to Git.  I have done this successfully (using git tfs) and was able to get the branches and version history to come along for the ride as well.  The issue I'm running into now, is that some of the TFVC projects (to be converted) have Sprints & Work Items, as well as checkins associated with them that I want to be able to migrate over to the new Git project.  I'm using visual studio 2015.

I want to be able to migrate the sprints and work items over to the new project which uses git, and historically associate all of the check-ins (now commits).  I know that I can create new work items/sprints in Team Services, then associate git commits with the work items using the syntax `#{work item number}` but I don't know how to preserve (or re-link) the historical associations once I do the conversion.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have better read the [document page on the git-tfs github about how to migrate from TFVC](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md#migrate-toward-tfs2013-git-repository-keeping-workitems) ;-)

The workitems should have been migrated first to generate a mapping file and being able to export commits with this new association.

I have even fixed some bugs in the workitems tools to make it works for me. [Here is my repository](https://github.com/pmiossec/TotalTfsMigrationTool)

If you can't go back and do it again, perhaps you could migrate your work items using this tool and write a tool that use the TFS api to read the workitems associated for each changeset, use the mapping file to find the new workitem id and use the git-tfs metadata in each commit to associate the work item to the commit, here again using the TFS api... 
Boring but not impossible...

And if you open source the tool, I will be very happy (and could even package it with git-tfs!)  ;-)

Comment: You are totally right - it occurred to me late last night "maybe git-tfs already does this....hmm, I should re-read through those docs" :)!  I started getting familiar with the TFS API yesterday and will need some more time, but this is something that I will likely continue to pursue...I'll let you know if/when I have something worth sharing!  Fortunately I was able to drop the project from VSO and re-create it, but not all the check-in work item associations are coming along so I'm looking into that.  Thanks again!